# SQLite collaboratibe editing in Mergin-Maps

Tags: sqlite, mergin-maps

I've QGIS project using SpatiaLite database. I can see SQLite as a valid data provider in Mergin-Maps user documentation, but it is not listed as collaborative editing, only GeoPackage is. As SQLite is the support of GeoPackage and geodiff  is designed for SpatiaLite and PostGIS, is this just a mistake in the doc or if it is not will SQLite make available to collaborative editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mergin Maps collaborative editing is all based on the capabilities of [geodiff](https://github.com/MerginMaps/geodiff) library. Both GeoPackage (which is SQLite based with a specified structure and triggers) and "pure" SQLite are supported.

Comment: Thank you, so it's was just forgotten in the documentation. I will try it with a free account.